# Guessing pronumeral

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c$ are three positive whole numbers. Their sum is $117.$

- $a$ is a prime number
- $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$
- $c \geq b$

What is the greatest possible value of the product $abc$?

Comment: a is 23 or smaller :D
when a is 29 .... 29x2 + 29x2 +29 is bigger than 117

Comment: If $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$, what does this tell you about the sum $a+b+c$?

Comment: It is just some detective work. The prime $a$ divides $b$ and $c$ so divides $a+b+c$, which is $3^2\cdot 13$. Now there are only two possible $a$.

Comment: Oh i get it! is 13 since 9 is not prime!

Comment: $a$ is a prime factor of $117$, so it is $3$ or $13$. For the rest, play around a bit. As a hint, given the sum of two numbers, their prduct is biggest if the numbers are as close to each other as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the help  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $a + b + c = 117$.

We know that $b\leq c$ and both are multiples of $a$.

So $b = ma, \;c= na,\; m\leq n$

Then our sum is $$a + ma + na = a(1 + m + n)= 117,\;\text{for some}\; m, n \in \mathbb Z^+, m\leq n$$

So  $a$ is not only prime, but a prime factor of $117$.

What is the prime factorization of $117?$

There are two.

We can maximize the product of any two numbers by picking numbers as near as possible to one another.